# How to remove a specific character in a string but only if there are no numbers in that line in Linux

Tags: centos, sed, string, replace

I've been stumped with this seemingly simple-to-fix problem.. well, for a while.

Here's example output from the file I need to edit:

```
$cat file
George Washington
Geneva Convention
123,281,029 USD
342,019,929 EUR
```

I need to remove the spaces between "George Washington" and "Geneva Convention", but not the spaces between "123,281,029 USD" or "342,019,929 EUR".

Essentially, my goal here is to only remove the space between words in a line ONLY if there are no numbers in that line.

I've tried to edit the file via `grep -v [0-9] $file | sed 's/ //'`, but only way that will work is if I output to another file, but that would mean excluding all lines with numbers from the old file to the new file, which is not what I need..

I've tried some pretty ridiculous loops with grep and `sed` but nothing seems to work just right.

Again, here is the example output of the file:

```
$cat file
George Washington
Geneva Convention
123,281,029 USD
342,019,929 EUR
```

Here is my desired output:

```
$cat file
GeorgeWashington
GenevaConvention
123,281,029 USD
342,019,929 EUR
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed '/[0-9]/!s/ //g' filename
```

This would remove spaces on all lines that do not contain a digit.

Using `awk`:

```
awk '!/[0-9]/{gsub(" ", "", $0)};1' filename
```

For removing the space only between the first two words (here using GNU `sed` for `-r`, use `-E` instead on BSDs):

```
sed -r '/[0-9]/!s/([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)/\1\2/' filename
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for! Couldn't find the syntax anywhere for the "/[0-9]/!s/" part. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user62129 - if this answer solves your issue please take a minute and check the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will signify to everyone that your issue's been resolved.

Answer (score 7):

Using `perl`:

```
perl -ple 's/\s+//g unless /\d/' file
```

Answer (score 4):

For a more general approach, remove only those spaces that are between two letters. That way it can work even if lines have digits, it just ignores the spaces around the numbers:

```
perl -pe 's/([a-z])\s+([a-z])/$1$2/ig' file
```

That will, for example, turn `George and Harry 12 EUR` to `GerogeandHArry 12 EUR` and still work correctly for the cases in your example.